# Regex match every character and newline

Tags: php, regex

I want to filter some data using regex. As for now I have some text going over 2 lines and I tried to make the linebreak match with `[^.*]`. But it seems to not pass the newline and so it doesn't match any result on the second line. How can I include the linebreak? I tried something like `[^\n\r.*]` but it didn't worked out.

Comment: What language are you using? Regular expressions are different and match different things for different languages.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers -> check `m` and `s` modifiers.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm using php and preg_match

Comment: s modifier solved the problem!

Comment: Can you show some examples of what would match, and what would *not* match so that we can use that as a baseline for determining what sort of pattern should be used?

Comment: You do realize that the expression: `[^.*]` is a character class that matches _"any one character that is not a dot or an asterisk."_ don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

You could use the 's' option which forces the dot to match all new line characters, or if you don't have control over the underlying code you could try:

`([^.]|[.])`

This will match every character. The dot will sometimes not match the carriage return, new line.

## PHP example

```
<?php
$sourcestring="This is my.
super cool
test string";
preg_match_all('/([^.]|[.])/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => T
            [1] => h
            [2] => i
            [3] => s
            [4] =>  
            [5] => i
            [6] => s
            [7] =>  
            [8] => m
            [9] => y
            [10] => .
            [11] => 
            [12] => 

            [13] => s
            [14] => u
            [15] => p
            [16] => e
            [17] => r
            [18] =>  
            [19] => c
            [20] => o
            [21] => o
            [22] => l
            [23] => 
            [24] => 

            [25] => t
            [26] => e
            [27] => s
            [28] => t
            [29] =>  
            [30] => s
            [31] => t
            [32] => r
            [33] => i
            [34] => n
            [35] => g
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => T
            [1] => h
            [2] => i
            [3] => s
            [4] =>  
            [5] => i
            [6] => s
            [7] =>  
            [8] => m
            [9] => y
            [10] => .
            [11] => 
            [12] => 

            [13] => s
            [14] => u
            [15] => p
            [16] => e
            [17] => r
            [18] =>  
            [19] => c
            [20] => o
            [21] => o
            [22] => l
            [23] => 
            [24] => 

            [25] => t
            [26] => e
            [27] => s
            [28] => t
            [29] =>  
            [30] => s
            [31] => t
            [32] => r
            [33] => i
            [34] => n
            [35] => g
        )

)
```